# Get Facebook User Access Token With Facebook SDK in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, facebook

I know there is so many question like this before. But forgive me, I still cannot get the user access token. I know this code can only get the **App Access Token**, not the **User Access Token**. Please help me to get **User Access Token**. Here is my code:

```
using Facebook;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetToken
{
    internal sealed class FacebookLoginProvider : LoginProvider
    {
        public FacebookLoginProvider(LoginProviderInfoStruct pLoginInfo) : base(pLoginInfo)
        {
            if (loginInfo.ClientId == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(LoginProviderInfoStruct.ClientId));

            ApplicationId = loginInfo.ClientId;
        }

    public override string ProviderName => FaceBookProviderName;
    public override string ProviderAbbrName => "FB";

    private const string DefaultAuthorizationUrl = @"https://www.facebook.com/v14.0/dialog/oauth";
    private const string DefaultTokenUrl = @"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/oauth/access_token";

    protected override async Task processLogin(CancellationToken ct, string pzUserName = null)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        LoginName = LoginSid = null;

        var fbClient = new FacebookClient();

        var loginParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["client_id"] = loginInfo.ClientId,
            ["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
            ["response_type"] = "token",
            ["display"] = "popup",
            ["scope"] = string.Join(",", loginInfo.Scopes)
        };

        var loginUrl = fbClient.GetLoginUrl(loginParameters);

        Process.Start(loginUrl.ToString());

        using (var _cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var _ct = _cts.Token;

            try
            {
                _cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

                if (ct.CanBeCanceled)
                    ct.Register(() => _cts.Cancel());

                raiseOnLoginInfo(string.Format("Authenticating account on '{0}'...", loginUrl.ToString()));

                dynamic app_result = await fbClient.GetTaskAsync("oauth/access_token", new
                {
                    client_id = loginInfo.ClientId,
                    client_secret = loginInfo.ClientSecret,
                    grant_type = "client_credentials"
                });

                var app_accessToken = app_result.access_token;
            }
            catch
            {
                if (_ct.IsCancellationRequested || ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    throw new OperationCanceledException();

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Is there any other library of .NET that support .NET framework 4.8 to login to facebook and get access token. Please help me. Thank a lot.